# How to used select join with specify any fields in laravel5

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I want to to select from 3 table with Join in Laravel5 but it the first times for me

```
public function getJD($id){

    $result = [];
    $result = JournalDetail::select('journal_detail.*, jdId as journal_detail, jdJ_id as journal_detail.journal_id .............,tranId as transactions_requiry,..............')
        ->join('journal_requiry','journal_requiry.id','=','journal_detail.journal_id')
        ->leftJoin('transactions_requiry','transactions_requiry.id','=','journal_requiry.tran_id')
        ->where('journal_detail.journal_id','=',$id)->get();
    return $result;

}
```

Errors,

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 624: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as `as` from `tb_journal_detail` inner join `tb_journal_requiry` on `tb_journal_' at line 1 (SQL: select `tb_journal_detail`.* as `as` from `tb_journal_detail` inner join `tb_journal_requiry` on `tb_journal_requiry`.`id` = `tb_journal_detail`.`journal_id` left join `tb_transactions_requiry` on `tb_transactions_requiry`.`id` = `tb_journal_requiry`.`tran_id` where `tb_journal_detail`.`journal_id` = 26)
```

But I can't do this I don't know how to do in Laravel5.
Please help

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I have edit as above question you can check ity

Comment: Your query seems a beet strange, why do you name the colums like this? "jdJ_id as journal_detail.journal_id" , can you post your entire code there? it seems something wrong here

Comment: It all errors although I used small or big capittle letter

Comment: As you can see in the error, the query generated from your code is not correct. Again I'm asking why do you alias those columns like this?? "jdJ_id as journal_detail.journal_id . And where is the whole select?

Answer (score 1):

put `DB::raw(` after select so your query will be:

```
$result = JournalDetail::select(DB::raw('journal_detail.*, jdId as journal_detail, jdJ_id as journal_detail.journal_id .............,tranId as transactions_requiry,..............'))
        ->join('journal_requiry','journal_requiry.id','=','journal_detail.journal_id')
        ->leftJoin('transactions_requiry','transactions_requiry.id','=','journal_requiry.tran_id')
        ->where('journal_detail.journal_id','=',$id)->get();
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.journal_id from `tb_journal_detail` inner join `tb_journal_requiry` on `tb_jour' at line 1 (SQL: select journal_detail.*, jd_id as journal_detail.journal_id from `tb_journal_detail` inner join

Comment: your query is invalid, is jd_id field in your table? if yes and you want display by this way you can put journal_detail.journal_id in 2 backticks like this `journal_detail.journal_id`

Comment: Ah I think Mysql statement allow we change any mysql string like this right when We Join
Examples Uname as tableName.username so Uname is instead of username?right?How ever I can Used this structure in Codeigniter but I don't know in Larave5